# Django render loading page then load actual page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

My actual page that I want to load takes quite a bit of time because it querying an API for a lot of data (python is doing the backend querying). How can I render my loading page and then render my actual page when the data has been gathered.

What I am trying to do in my view.py

```
class Page(ListView):

       def loading(request):
            return render(request,'loading.html')

       def viewProfile(request, player_name):
            Page.loading(request)

            context = {
                'data1' : query_api(1),
                'data2' : query_api(2),
                'data3' : query_api(3),

            } 
            return render(request, 'actualpage.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loading page, make an `ajax` request to the view which will query the api, and in the success callback set the html data in your template.

However, if the api takes a lot of time, I would suggest you to use `celery` for processing it asynchronously so that your user can navigate the website normally instead of waiting.

In your template -

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<query_view_url>",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                $("#div_id").html(data.query_data);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

In your `views.py` -

```
def view_of_query_url(request, <other parameters>):
    <query_logic>
    data = dict()
    data['query_data'] = <your_queried_data>  # In html format using render_to_string
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the js being the querying and not python?

Comment: @AjayShah No, you send an ajax request to query the API, which will be handled in the views.py. Return the result from the view in a `JsonResponse` which will be received in the success callback. Then set the result in an html element like `div`

Comment: Can you show me an example of what this method would look like?

Comment: @AjayShah Look at my updated answer. Set the `<your_queried_data>` using `render_to_string` to make it like an html. You can google it